# how to get the month start and end minisecond in dart

Tags: dart

I want to using dart `Dart SDK version: 2.17.3 (stable) (Wed Jun 1 11:06:41 2022 +0200) on "macos_arm64"` to get start and end minisecond of current month.  I tried like this but I did not know how to get the last day `23:59:59:999` unix timestamp:

```
  endOfMonthMilliseconds(DateTime now) {
    var beginningNextMonth = (now.month < 12) ? new DateTime(now.year, now.month + 1, 1) : new DateTime(now.year + 1, 1, 1);
    var lastDay = beginningNextMonth.subtract(new Duration(days: 1)).millisecondsSinceEpoch;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using UTC dates, because then you won't get into daylight saving issues, but if you do the need local time end-of-month, this *should* work:

```dart
DateTime endOfMonth(DateTime now) {
  return DateTime(now.year, now.month + 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1);
}
```

The `DateTime` constructor allows overflow and underflow between fields, so `DateTime(now.year, now.month + 1, 1)` would give you the first of the following month (no need to do the December-to-January overflow yourself), and appending the `, 0, 0, 0, -1` should give you one millisecond earlier than that.